# Unable to load tp_smapi on Thinkpad w541

Tags: 14.04, power-management, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad w541 with Haswell Procesor (i7-4810MQ ). I am unable to load the a Thinkpad module for battery improvement.

joselugo@joselugo:~$ sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 0.7 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)<<<<<<<<<<

tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SMP
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1149
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  56160 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  56040 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  55950 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     96 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

I read this:
If you are installing on a recent Thinkpad that has an Ivy Bridge or newer processor (X230, T430, T530, etc.), tp_smapi will not work. You will be mostly limited to thinkpad-acpi capabilities. You can however set battery charge thresholds with tpacpi-bat.

Here:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Installation_on_Ubuntu

Can anyone confirm if the Thinkpad w541 falls on this category?

I am having terrible battery performance, I have installed powertop, tdp,  thinkpad modules, THERMALD AND INTEL P-STATE. I am not seeing to much difference since I have installed/uninstalled them and combining them without much success. I would love to hear the comments from someone having the same laptop and seeing their results with their battery performance.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

tp-smapi doesn't support your hardware. Your output shows that tpacpi-bat works. Try to recalibrate your battery as described in the [manual](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#recalibrate).

EDITH: i had a closer look into your output. Your battery doesn't need recalibration (design cap 0 56040 mAh vs. last full = 55950 mAh).

So i guess the reason for your fast battery drain is something else, probably the infamous Nvidia Optimus hybrid graphics.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I had to remove Ubuntu because of this issue. Your pointer about Nvidia graphics seem interesting. Do you have any link regarding this issue so I can check it and try to reinstall Ubuntu on a second SSD? This laptop has an extra bay and probably I can try that without disrupting my current "forced" Windows environment. I would like to understand the issue and the workaround. The only thing that I regarding that front was to install the official Nvidia driver and set it to Intel only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [laptop-mode](http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode) instead. This page is useful for [installation on Ubuntu 15.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/09/install-laptop-mode-tools-ubuntu-1510/)